# Adding a "read" button which will add to progress

Tags: php

i'm working on a project and there will be a page for students to read the content. My progress is based on how much content they have read so can someone help me implement a "read" button where when the button is clicked/checked, it will add the progress onto their progress. This should also show what they content they have read, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example with PHP and AJAX:

HTML

Hello, click this button to read: Click me

```
<!-- including jQuery from the google cdn -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
// This is our actual script
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a#button').click(function(){
         $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: {variable:"1"},
            url: "ajax.php",
              success: function(data) { $("#container").html(data) }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

PHP - ajax.php

```
<?php

session_start(); // using session instead of database for example


$_SESSION['student_progress']++;

echo json_encode("You just marked " . $_POST['variable'] . " as readed and your progress was updated to ". $_SESSION['student_progress'] );
```